# UiScrollable not working as expected in UiAutomator

Tags: android, uiscrollview, scrollable, android-uiautomator

I am new to programming with UIautomator and needed to select an option "Device" from settings using scroll.

This is the code that I wrote:

```
public class LaunchClass extends UiAutomatorTestCase {

    public static final UiSelector LAUNCHER_ITEM = new UiSelector().className(android.widget.TextView.class.getName());


    public void testDemo() throws UiObjectNotFoundException {
          //new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Email")).clickAndWaitForNewWindow();

        getUiDevice().pressHome();
        UiObject settingsClick = new UiObject(new UiSelector().description("Settings. App. Item *23 of *24 on page *1."));    
        settingsClick.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
        UiScrollable scroll = new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true));
        scroll.setAsVerticalList();
        sleep(5000);
        UiObject voiceButton = scroll.getChildByText(LaunchClass.LAUNCHER_ITEM, "Device");
        sleep(5000);
        voiceButton.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
```

While executing this it scrolls down but does not select "Device", i thought maybe the scroll the slower than the click so introduced a sleep - but its no good.

This is the error that I get:

Error in testDemo:

```
com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObjectNotFoundException: for text= "Voice"
    at com.android.uiautomator.core.UiCollection.getChildByText(UiCollection.java:125)
    at com.android.uiautomator.core.UiScrollable.getChildByText(UiScrollable.java:201)
    at com.android.uiautomator.core.UiScrollable.getChildByText(UiScrollable.java:181)
    at com.uia.example.my.Sairam.testDemo(Sairam.java:23)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestRunner.start(UiAutomatorTestRunner.java:144)
    at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestRunner.run(UiAutomatorTestRunner.java:87)
    at com.android.commands.uiautomator.RunTestCommand.run(RunTestCommand.java:90)
    at com.android.commands.uiautomator.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:83)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:235)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stack=com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObjectNotFoundException: for text= "Voice"
    at com.android.uiautomator.core.UiCollection.getChildByText(UiCollection.java:125)
    at com.android.uiautomator.core.UiScrollable.getChildByText(UiScrollable.java:201)
    at com.android.uiautomator.core.UiScrollable.getChildByText(UiScrollable.java:181)
    at com.uia.example.my.Sairam.testDemo(Sairam.java:23)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestRunner.start(UiAutomatorTestRunner.java:144)
    at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestRunner.run(UiAutomatorTestRunner.java:87)
    at com.android.commands.uiautomator.RunTestCommand.run(RunTestCommand.java:90)
    at com.android.commands.uiautomator.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:83)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:235)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testDemo
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
Test results for WatcherResultPrinter=.E
Time: 10.974

FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 1,  Failures: 0,  Errors: 1
```

Would appreciate if someone could point out what am I doing wrong, this is my 1st time and any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are two things here:

1. Error log shows that you have changed your code, but haven't compiled it again :)

   `com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObjectNotFoundException: for text= "Voice"` ? -- As per your code it should have seached for `"Device"` instead
2. Use `UiObject voiceButton = scroll.getChild(new UiSelector().className("android.widget.TextView").text("Device"));` instead of `UiObject voiceButton = scroll.getChildByText(LaunchClass.LAUNCHER_ITEM, "Device");`.

I don't really think you need `sleep` if you have `clickAndWaitForNewWindow()`

Comment: sorry I was searching for both "Voice" and "Device" both were scrolled down. Thanks will try it and see!